# A que se debe este error en PHP con SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, yii2

¡Hola!

Después de una larga espera al fin, me toca desarrollar un sistema utilizando `Yii2` y `SQL Server`.

Me he descargado el XAMPP con su PHP 5.6.31 y me he instalado el SQL Server 2008 y no consigo realizar la conexión a la base de datos.

He probado ya descargando las versiones oficiales de drivers de SQL Server para PHP de Microsoft utilizando este enlace:

[Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

Tambien he activado la extensiones en el archivo `php.ini`

`extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll`
`extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll`
`extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` 
`extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll`

Mi archivo de configuracion a la base de datos es el siguiente:

```
return [
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=127.0.0.1;Database=softwareoperacional',
'username' => 'sa',
'password' => 'admin123',
'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Como mensaje de error me sale lo siguiente:

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Revise el PHPInfo y muestra lo siguiente en el PDO Drivers
[image: Revise el PHPInfo y muestra lo siguiente en el PDO Drivers]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me conecto a mi gestor de base de datos de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien por acá sería tan amable de decirme que estoy haciendo mal en la configuracion o que version debo instalar?

De antemano, gracias por vuestra atención, si hay algo que haga falta con gusto lo reviso, quedo pendiente

Saludos,

Comment: Revisa si estás usando el driver correcto. Porque en el dsn veo que tienes mssql, ein embargo estás activando el driver sqlsrv. Intenta esto, 'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=mydatabase',

Comment: Ya lo intente tal cual como le dices pero aun no me conecta

Comment: Revisa mi ultima edición se me olvida agregar mi mensaje de error

Comment: Pusiste los drivers en la carpeta xampp\php\ext y reiniciaste el apache de xampp?

Comment: Claro que si mi amigo copie todos los archivos .dll a la carpeta  xampp\php\ext y tambien reinicie el apache. Alguna otra solución ?

Comment: Con la versión de PHP que usas, deberías usar las extensiones php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll y php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll o para PDO php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll y php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

Comment: Al momento de cambiar la extensión por las que me nombraste anteriormente me sale un mensaje de error al reiniciar el apache de xamp "El programa no puede iniciarse porque falta php5.dll en el equipo."

Comment: Descarga de esta página el archivo php5.dll  http://windows.php.net/download/  y colocalo en xampp/apache/bin

Comment: Descargue el archivo php5.dll lo coloque en la carpeta xampp/apache/bin no me sale el mensaje de error que decia que me falta php5.dll, pero aun me sigue saliendo el error de "exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php:646"

Comment: Podrías ingresar a localhost/dashboard en la opción PHPInfo. Revisa en la tabla que tiene el titulo PDO y debajo dice PDO support. Al frente hay una columna llamada enabled. Que te aparece ahí?

Comment: Revise PHPInfo en la tabla que tiene el titulo PDO, en la columna enabled me aparece lo siguiente "mysql, pgsql, sqlite" @RaulA.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73909/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-raul-a).

Comment: Cambia en el dsn el server por "Server=SEBASTIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Bajar el driver ODBC para SQL Server.
2. Habilitar las extensiones extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll y extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll en el PHP.ini.
3. Agregar las extensiones que se habilitaron en la ruta xampp\php\ext .
4. Reiniciar XAMPP.
5. Cambiar el string de conexión 'sqlsrv:Server=127.0.0.1;Database=softwareoperacional' y colocar este
   'sqlsrv:Server=SEBASTIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=softwareoperacional'.

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente aun no tienes instalado el driver correspondiente, te dejo la documentación de microsoft al respecto.

[Click aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver)

Por otra parte, en la configuración del PHP ini debes agregar

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_XX_ts.dll
```

según corresponda.

Comment: Que extensión debo utilizar si estoy usando php 5.6.31?

Comment: No tengo la respuesta concreta, pero instala el más actualizado y prueba

Comment: Tienes la cadena de conexión correcta para intentarlo.Gracias quedo pendiente

Answer (score -2):

Además de estas extensiones `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll` y `extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll`, debes habilitar también `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll`